# Randomize and Loop Questions in Android App Quiz

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting confused. I am developing a quiz. I have been trying to randomize questions. I tried to randomize within the Cursor and Rawquery to no avail.

At the same time, I want the app to loop questions after the last one.

Here is my Question.java (this is my activity)

```
public class Question extends Activity {


    public static final String TAG = Question.class.getSimpleName();
    private TextView mTimer;
    private Button mTimerButton;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;
    private Button mNextQuestion;
    private Button mHowtoplay2;
    List<QuestionFaci> quesList;
    int qid = 0;

    QuestionFaci currentQ;

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState( outState );


    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState( savedInstanceState );


    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_question );

        mHowtoplay2 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.howtoplaybutton );
        mHowtoplay2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startHowtoplay();
            }
        } );


        QuizHelper db = new QuizHelper( this );
        quesList = db.getAllQuestions();
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid);

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.questionView  );
        mNextQuestion = (Button)findViewById( R.id.nextbutton );

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                setQuestionView();
            }
        };

        mNextQuestion.setOnClickListener( listener );
        Log.d(TAG, "We're logging from the onCreate() method");


    private void startHowtoplay(){
        Intent intent = new Intent( this, Howtoplay.class );
        startActivity( intent );
    }
    private void setQuestionView(){
        mQuestionTextView.setText( currentQ.getQUESTION() );
        qid++;
    }
}
```

Here is my QuizHelper

```
public class QuizHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "creativequestion";
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "qid";
    private static final String KEY_QUEST = "question";

    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;

    public QuizHelper(Context context) {
        super( context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase = db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( " + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUEST + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL( sql );
        addQuestion();
    }

    private void addQuestion() {

        QuestionFaci q1 = new QuestionFaci( "OTHER USES: Name other uses of a Hammer. \n\n Example: Stir a soup." );
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        QuestionFaci q2 = new QuestionFaci( "RHYMES: Words that rhymes with Rice. \n\n Example: Ice" );
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        QuestionFaci q3 = new QuestionFaci( "WITH: I can cook eggs with... \n\n Example: A Piece of Plywood" );
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        QuestionFaci q4 = new QuestionFaci( "WITHOUT: I can wash my clothes without... \n\n Example: My Aunt" );
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        QuestionFaci q5 = new QuestionFaci( "I WILL: If I was Bill Gates, I will... \n\n Example: Buy a spaceship" );
        this.addQuestion(q5);
        QuestionFaci q6 = new QuestionFaci( "CREATE A MOVIE TITLE: A NIGHT \n\n Example: To Remember" );
        this.addQuestion(q6);
        QuestionFaci q7 = new QuestionFaci( "OTHER NAMES: Other names of a cow \n\n Example: Milk giver" );
        this.addQuestion(q7);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_QUEST );
        onCreate( db );

    }
    private void addQuestion(QuestionFaci quest) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(  );
        values.put(KEY_QUEST, quest.getQUESTION());
        dbase.insert( TABLE_QUEST, null, values );
    }


    public List<QuestionFaci> getAllQuestions(){
        List<QuestionFaci> quesList = new ArrayList<QuestionFaci>(  );
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery( selectQuery, null );
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                QuestionFaci quest = new QuestionFaci(  );
                quest.setID( cursor.getInt( 0 ) );
                quest.setQUESTION( cursor.getString( 1 ) );

                quesList.add(quest);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
         }

        return quesList;

    }
}
```

Here is my QuestionFaci where my getters and setters

```
public class QuestionFaci extends Activity {

    private int ID;
    private String QUESTION;

    public QuestionFaci(){

        ID=0;
        QUESTION= "";

    }

    public QuestionFaci (String qUESTION){
        QUESTION = qUESTION;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return ID;
    }

    public String getQUESTION(){
        return QUESTION;
    }

    public void setID(int id){
        ID = id;
    }

    public void setQUESTION(String qUESTION){
        QUESTION = qUESTION;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with this :

```
private void setQuestionView(){
    Random r = new Random();
    int Low = 0;
    int High = quesList.size();
    int Result = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low; // 0 - questions size() -> select random
    qid = Result; 
    mQuestionTextView.setText( currentQ.getQUESTION() ); // set Question

}
```

If you want previous questions not to appear again you have to do it in a different way.

P.S : This does not randomize your questions in your database. It randomizes the qid so it gives you a random question from your list. You could randomize the list that you get from the database, and if you use a HashMap then you will know if a question has appeared before or not.

Comment: Do you know how I can loop back after my quiz shows the last question from the database?

Comment: The last question of the database or the last question that it will be shown? currently the above answer just set ups random questions, it could still show the same question. If you want every question not to appear again then you will have to use a boolean value which will be set to true after each question is shown. What do you mean by "loop back"?

Comment: I figured it out Tony. I placed a if and else statement. I was wanting to loop the questions regardless of method reaching the very last item question in my database. Before, it got to point that app crashes as soon as it shows the last question within my database.

Comment: How to randomize  questions from database Andrew Jake Villegas ??